# Run code every min in foreground service

Tags: android

How can I set a timer, within a service that is running in foreground, so it runs a piece of code every 1 min. In pseudo code I want smth like this.

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    startEveryMinTask()

    return START_STICKY;
}

private void startEveryMinTask() {
    //do stuf
}
```

Comment: use the alarm manager

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `java.util.Timer`

```
Timer timer = new Timer();

public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
           startEveryMinTask();
        }, 60000, 60000); // 60000 milliseconds = 1 minute

    return START_STICKY;
}
```

Comment: this will run every min for sure?

Comment: I'm sure you're aware of the android politic after **Android Oreo (8.0)** -> in terms of services, we need to use ```foregroundService```. But if in a foreground service we use ```Task``` does it count as a background service?

Answer (score 0):

Just Use AlarmManager to shoot an intent to invoke your service again after its done with its code.

Comment: And this will not start a new service every min?

Comment: yes it will and it should. As once the service is done it should destroy itself. and let the alarm invoke it again.

Comment: No if I want to keep a foreground service.

Comment: You just cannot assure it running without getting destroyrd AFAIK

Comment: From google ---> "A foreground service is a service that's considered to be something the user is actively aware of and thus not a candidate for the system to kill when low on memory." [link]http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground

Comment: @Nuno you figured a way what to use? I'm dealing with exactly the same problem - foreground service and an updating time chronometer inside it.