# Timer that run every seconds on android eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

Hi every one can you help to create a 5 seconds timer that runs for every 3 or 5 seconds.. im new in android pls help me

i have only created a 5 seconds timer but it only run once.. i want it to run for every 5 seconds..

and here is my code :

```
    txt1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);


    final Handler handler = new Handler();

  TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
      @Override
        public void run() {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                // pos=rand.nextInt(10);
                 //txt1.setText(""+pos);

                    if(Integer.parseInt(txt1.getText().toString()) != 0)
                    {
                        txt1.setText("" + (Integer.parseInt(txt1.getText().toString()) - 1));
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        };

    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(task, 1000, 1000);
```

Thx :)

Comment: Similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27986005/run-code-every-min-in-foreground-service/27986235#27986235.

Comment: Have you ever used an actual timer? You know you need to reset them so they trigger again. . .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using below code, handler calls itself again and again.

```
final Handler handler = new Handler(); 
        Runnable runable = new Runnable() { 

        @Override 
        public void run() { 
         try{
           if(Integer.parseInt(txt1.getText().toString()) != 0)
             {
               txt1.setText("" + (Integer.parseInt(txt1.getText().toString()) - 1));
             }
                handler.postDelayed(this, 3000);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                //  handle exception
            }
        } 
    }; 
    handler.postDelayed(runable, 5000);
```

Comment: my app is crashing sir, its getting out of memory, are there any other ways?

Comment: Made a mistake, finally was not required. The basic idea is to call it multiple times, just like recursion.

Comment: when i add my code into yours the timer didnt restart, it just got stucked at 0. look what i did sir

Comment: well it is still stuck at 0 and didnt restart, but good thing that it is not crashing now,